# Xserver crashes while turning on the second screen with new nvidia driver on 14.04

Tags: drivers, xorg, multiple-monitors, 14.04, nvidia-optimus

I have recently updated Kubuntu to 14.04 and installed new nvidia drivers for my GT 630m (optimus). 
After upgrade my second display connected over HDMI with DVI adapter was turned off, so I tried to turn it on in system settings and I get

```
kmsserver failes to start. check your installation
```

then xserver crashes and restarts.

It's also interesting, that if I connect the second display over VGA, it works fine, until I try to change the configuration from system settings.

How to fix it?